# Wordpress IP to local dns URL RHEL8

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, ubuntu, redhat

so I have two instances using AWS, one is RHEL8 and it's in a private subnet, the other one is ubuntu in a public subnet. I have a wordpress site on the redhat one and I changed the site URL to the IP of the machine, this way the public instance can access it through http://(ip)/wordpress

[image]

[image]

It's working and all that but what I just wanna know is how I can configure the URL to be something like say [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with local DNS

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit `/etc/hosts` on ubuntu server, append a domain mapping for RHEL8 server

```
172.16.6.143 www.example.com
```

2. In wordpress admin portal, edit site address, replace 172.16.6.143 with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
3. On RHEL8 server, configure server_name for the wordpress (nginx/apache)

```
# nginx virtual host
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

reload http server

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

if everything goes well, you can visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) from the ubuntu server